# Convert multiple csv files to json using python

Tags: json, python-3.x, csv

I am trying to convert csv files in a folder to a single json file. Below code does the job, but the issue is, json file has the first csv written several times. Below is the code i tried. I guess i am going wrong with assigning the data variable. Help me fix it

```py
import csv, json, os
dir_path = 'C:/Users/USER/Desktop/output_files'
inputfiles = [file for file in os.listdir(dir_path) if file.endswith('.csv')]
outputfile = "data_backup1.json"

for file in inputfiles:
    filepath = os.path.join(dir_path, file)
    data = {}
    with open(filepath, "r") as csvfile:       
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        for row in reader:
            id = row['ID']
            data[id] = row

    with open(outputfile, "a") as jsonfile:
        jsonfile.write(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
```

Expected output: Json file needs to have each csv written only once into it.

Answer (score 0):

if your .csv files and all of the rows do have different `['ID']`s, your assigned dictionary keys should be unique. In this case, your dictionary is growing with one entry per reader .csv row.

You have to change the indentation of the jsonfile.write() function as shown below to produce just one .json file. To sort your entries you could add `sort_keys=True` in this function.

```
for file in inputfiles:
    filepath = os.path.join(dir_path, file)
    data = {}
    with open(filepath, "r") as csvfile:       
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        for row in reader:
            id = row['ID']
            data[id] = row

with open(outputfile, "a") as jsonfile:
    jsonfile.write(json.dumps(data, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
```